# WCF REST Return List in Json

Tags: c#, json, wcf, list, rest

I want to respond a List in WCF with Rest in JSON format. How can i do that to receive my Users? Endpointconfiguration already works.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetUsers")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetUsers", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<User> GetUsers();
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I don't receive any information in the Browser or fiddler. I would like to receive a List of my own user class. How can i send List<CustomClass> with JSON?

Comment: @user3698577, what do you receive back from fiddler?

Comment: @christiandev 512, 504.. completly random. Dont know. I remote debug, and everything works fine, also the return doesn't even mess up. So it have to be that "List<Users>" cannot be "interpreted"

Comment: What does the `User` class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that i had a class  defined in the IInterface.cs.
But in that class I had a subclass, lets say for example "dog".

Now I set up the [DataContract] for "user", but not for "dog", which was unfortunately included into "user".

**Solution: "For every class that should be returned, dont forgett the [DataContract]"**

The tricky thing on that stuff is, you dont even have any warnings, exceptions etc.

Greets and thanks!

Comment: for me, after adding the [datacontract] , its not getting resoled. whats the namespace for this [DataContract] .? please help